# How do I adjust the size of dots when generating QR Codes in itext7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have a question while using itext7. I want to generate a pdf by generating a QR code.
There is no problem with normal creation. However, I want to adjust the size of the dots of the QR.
I don't want to reduce the overall size of the QR code, I just want to reduce the size of the dots in it.
Currently, only the overall size of the QR code can be adjusted.

```
public class PdfTest {

    public static final String DEST = "D:\\output.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "D:\\202106003196.pdf";

    static PdfDocument mPdfDocument;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            File file = new File(DEST);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    
            FontProgramFactory.registerFont("D:\\font\\MAISONNEUEEXT-MEDIUM.OTF", "MAISONNEUEEXT-MEDIUM");
            PdfFont mPdfFont_MAISONNEUEEX_MEDIUM = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("MAISONNEUEEXT-MEDIUM");

            mPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));

            Document mDocument = new Document(mPdfDocument);
            
            // QR
            addQR("HTTP://QR.TEST.COM/0123456", mPdfDocument, 1, 25, 50);
            
            PdfPage pdfPage = mPdfDocument.getPage(1);

            Rectangle pageSize = pdfPage.getPageSize();
            Rectangle[] mRectangle = {new Rectangle(0, 10, pageSize.getRight(), 50)};
            mDocument.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(mDocument, mRectangle));

            mDocument.close();
            mPdfDocument.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void addQR(String mQRCode, PdfDocument mPdfDocument, int mPage, float mX, float mY) {

        PdfPage mPdfPage = mPdfDocument.getPage(mPage);
        BarcodeQRCode mBarcodeQRCode;
        Map<EncodeHintType, Object> mHints = new HashMap<>();
        mHints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
        mHints.put(EncodeHintType.MIN_VERSION_NR, 2);
        mBarcodeQRCode = new BarcodeQRCode(mQRCode, mHints);
        
        PdfCanvas over = new PdfCanvas(mPdfPage);

        mBarcodeQRCode.placeBarcode(over, ColorConstants.RED, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RYH6.png)

Comment: Hi, you shared a method declaration. How (with which parameters) shall this method be called to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @AlexeySubach
Hello, I modified the source above. I brought back the full source code.
The above source code does not generate an error.
What I want is to reduce the size of the dots in the QR code.

Answer (score 1):

The size of dots is defined by QR-algorithm itself and depends on the length of the content. Let me modify your code to demonstrate it.

In the snippet below we will add 10 QR codes: the first one will represent just one "Lorem ipsum" sentence, the last one - 10 sentences.

```
@Test
public void barcodesTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destinationFolder + "barcodes.pdf"));

    String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pdfDocument.addNewPage();
        builder.append(text);
        addQR(builder.toString(), pdfDocument, i+1);
    }

    pdfDocument.close();
}

private static void addQR(String text, PdfDocument pdfDoc, int pageNumber) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(pageNumber);

    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> mHints = new HashMap<>();
    mHints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
    mHints.put(EncodeHintType.MIN_VERSION_NR, 2);

    BarcodeQRCode qrCode = new BarcodeQRCode(text, mHints);

    PdfCanvas over = new PdfCanvas(page);
    // 12 is passed to make the qr code appear big
    qrCode.placeBarcode(over, ColorConstants.RED, 12);
}
```

If we compare the barcodes, we will see that the size of the dots is reduced gradually page by page (in fact, the barcode on the last page is so huge, that it occupies far more space than the page itself):
The first page: [image]
The last page: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the meaning of my question is as follows:
QR data is in the same state, only the size of the dots is different.
Please check the comparison image that I additionally attached. Thanks

Comment: Isn't the image on the right side a bit more narrow then the image on the left? If that's the case, then you decrease a bit the third argument in ` qrCode.placeBarcode(over, ColorConstants.RED, 12);`

Comment: If you adjust the size of the third factor of '111', the size of the entire QR is adjusted.
I want to adjust only the size of the dots without changing the size of the entire QR.